# QuantLib Test Question: Error C4996 'QuantLib::CalibratedModel::calibrate': was declared deprecated

Tags: c++, quantlib

I am new to QuantLib. Just following the instruction on website (https://www.quantlib.org/install/vc10.shtml), I successfully build the QuantLib solution in VS 2017. Then still following the instruction, I create a new project named "QuantLib_Test" with the following codes:

```
#include <ql/quantlib.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    QuantLib::Calendar myCal = QuantLib::UnitedKingdom();
    QuantLib::Date newYearsEve(31, QuantLib::Dec, 2008);

    std::cout << "Name: " << myCal.name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "New Year is Holiday: " << myCal.isHoliday(newYearsEve) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "New Year is Business Day: " << myCal.isBusinessDay(newYearsEve) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "--------------- Date Counter --------------------" << std::endl;

    QuantLib::Date date1(28, QuantLib::Dec, 2008);
    QuantLib::Date date2(04, QuantLib::Jan, 2009);

    std::cout << "First Date: " << date1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Second Date: " << date2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Business Days Betweeen: " << myCal.businessDaysBetween(date1, date2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "End of Month 1. Date: " << myCal.endOfMonth(date1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "End of Month 2. Date: " << myCal.endOfMonth(date2) << std::endl;

    double tmp;
    std::cin >> tmp;

    return 0;
}
```

However it shows the error message: `Error  C4996   'QuantLib::CalibratedModel::calibrate': was declared deprecated`

Thank you if anyone can help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have told the compiler to treat warnings as errors.  Either relax that, or disable warning C4996.

If possible, upgrading to VS 2019 should also avoid the problem.